# Excel VBA for Alt hotkeys automation/simulation?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to automate adding "conditional formatting" > "color scales" using VBA script. But as I google it, I couldn't find any solution. But I thought if it's possible to automate/simulate Excel hotkeys, such as "alt > H > L > S", it should be possible. So I'd like to know if there is a way for that?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to forget about "alt > H > L > S" and try focusing on a detailed explanation about what you need accomplishing. It should be done in VBA... I mean, I would like to validate the range "B1:B10", using Color Scales (3-color scale), format based on the cell value, midpoint - percentile etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it may be possible to find a solution by simulating keystrokes (this can be done with `SendKeys`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) - don't go down that path. Be assured that this will never work reliable, too many things can go wrong.

It's not that hard to set conditional formatting using VBA. The following two procedures set a color scale to a range, the first a simple 2-color scale, the second a 3-color. If you need other variations, use the Macro recorder to learn how to set the correct properties.

```
Sub setScaleCondition(r As Range)
    Dim cScale As ColorScale
    Set cScale = r.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=2)
    
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = vbRed
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = vbGreen
End Sub


Sub setScaleCondition3(r As Range)
    Dim cScale As ColorScale
    Set cScale = r.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
    
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = vbRed
    
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    cScale.ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = vbGreen
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to color multiple-ranged range with the function? For example, like `$J$2:$J$26,$U$2:$U$26,$AF$2:$AF$26`. I tried `Call setScaleCondition3(Range(ranges))` ("ranges" is String the ranges text) but apparently not working.

Comment: ah my bad. it does work. I needed to "ActiveSheet.Range" not "Range". thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. It will add Color Scales conditional formatting on the range "B1:B10" of the active sheet:

```
Sub CondFormColorScale()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = sh.Range("B1:B10")
   rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    With rng
        .FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = vbRed
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = vbYellow
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = vbGreen
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, play with numbers in the conditional formatted range and send some feedback...

Comment: great. as I'm running the exact script I got an error "Subscript Out of Range (Run time: Error 9)", is this fixable?

Comment: @pupsozeyde: It should be, but only mentioning the error does not help so much, if you do not specify the code line where it appears... Firstly, did you try the code exactly as it is? The code has been tested on my computer and worked as expected.

Comment: the only thing I can know is the error message. Is there any way to know where on the lines an error happened or advanced debug way?

Comment: @FaneDuru: Replace `Selection` with `rng` should solve that problem...

Comment: @pupsozeyde Just press the "Debug"-button when the error happens, that lead you into the VBA editor and highlights the line issuing the error.

Comment: @FunThomas: I am looking to the code and I am not able to see any `Selection`... I am sure, it must be somewhere, but I cannot see it. Ups. I observed it... Thanks!

Comment: @pupsozeyde: please, test the updated code (without 'Selection'). It happened, in my computer, I wanted to see the rule as it has been created and the range has been selected. That's why it worked...